# Add rating functionality in message board portlet in liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have to give rating functionality in message board portlet. for that I have created hook and override view.jsp file of message board portlet. I have added `"liferay-ui:rating"` tag as

```
  liferay-ui:ratings

  className="<%= MBMessage.class.getName() %>"

  classPK="<%= message.getMessageId() %>"

  type="stars"
```

I am getting error while deploying. what should be the values for className and classPK. Also from where can I get class name for message board and class primary key for the same.

Comment: what is the error you are getting? Please use message.getClassPK() instead of message.getMessageId()

Comment: Any reason for removing below answer as accepted?

Comment: At my case message.getMessageId() is giving me correct values, where as  message.getClassPK() was throwing exception.

Answer (score 1):

Have it as shown below.

```
<liferay-ui:ratings

className="<%= MBMessage.class.getName() %>"

classPK="<%= message.getClassPK() %>"

type="stars"/>
```